# Finding a word on a dictionary in a string C# and the value of that word

Tags: c#, dictionary, .net-4.5

Right now I have this code which checks if a string has a any word in a dictionary:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using PlayerIOClient;

public static Connection conn;
public static Client client;
public static Dictionary<int, string> users = new Dictionary<int, string>();
public static Dictionary<string, string> corList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
public bool isConnected;

static void OnMessage(object sender, PlayerIOClient.Message m)
{
    if (m.Type == "init")
    {
        conn.Send("access", wldcode);
        conn.Send("init2");
        corList.Add("hes", "he's"); //Example of one item on the list.
        conn.Send("say", "Grammar fixer bot connected. Repare to be corrected.");
    }
    if (m.Type == "add")
    {
        users.Add(m.GetInt(0), m.GetString(1));
    }
    if (m.Type == "left")
    {
        users.Remove(m.GetInt(0));
    }
    if (m.Type == "say")
    {
        if (users.ContainsKey(m.GetInt(0)))
        {
            string username = users[m.GetInt(0)];

            if (corList.Keys.Any(m.GetString(1).Contains)) //Problem is here.
            { //m.GetString(1) Are usually long strings, such as sentences.
                conn.Send("say", "Grammar Fixer: " + corList[]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am not able to get the specific key that was detected in the word or the value of this key. This dictionary is also going to hold a lot of definitions, so just having the if then for one specific word will not work.

Comment: Googling "MSDN .Net" or ".net tutorial" plus whatever you are trying to do is one the first tool a programmer should use. Just like multimeters for peoples doing electronics. Please use your tools adequatly to avoid downvotes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var key = m.GetString(1);
string correction = null;
if (corList.TryGetValue(key, out correction))
{
    conn.Send("say", string.format("Grammar Fixer: {0}, not {1}!", correction, key));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing what `corList` is or what `m.GetString(1).Contains` is. So I have to do a lot of guessing about what you want to do, but you can try this:

```
var key = m.GetString(1);

if (corList.Keys.Any(key))
{
    conn.Send("say", string.format("Grammar Fixer: {0}, not {1}!", corList[key], key));
}
```

Comment: Did you mean "...string.format("Grammar Fixer: {0}, not {1}!", corList[key], key)) ?